# Cast While Looping Over Dictionary in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a dictionary of `AnyObject` and I want to loop over it getting the keys and values but cast both to a `String` while doing so

```
var headers: [NSObject : AnyObject] = [:]
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/pdf"

for (key, value) in headers {
    println(key)
    println(value)
}
```

I thought it would be something like the following but this gives me `Type '(String, String)' does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType'`

```
for (key, value) in headers as (String, String) {
    println(key)
    println(value)
}
```

I know that I could just do it inline like `(key as! String)` but I would think that you could just cast it as your looping. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: not a swift expert, but shouldn't that be something like `for (key, value) as (String, String) in headers` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're asking the compiler to iterate over `headers` as a tuple of Strings, but `headers` is a dictionary, not a tuple.

The solution is to cast the entire `headers` dictionary at once with the right type, key as String and value as String, like this:

```
for (key, value) in headers as! [String:String] {
    println(key)
    println(value)
}
```

Of course, beware that it will crash if any of the keys or values are not a String.

You would have to iterate over the dictionary with its original type then cast as String *inside* the loop with safety checks if you're not sure all your keys and values are Strings.

Comment: Or you could use optional binding `if let dict = headers as? [String: String] { for (key, value) in dict ...`

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response and the in-depth explanation!

Comment: @vacawama Yes, you're right. It's a good idea to check if the cast works with optional binding if we're not sure about the content types.

Comment: btw, in Swift 2.0 you can now also write `for case let (key as String, value as String) in headers` which will only iterate over matching elements, ignoring non-matching

Comment: @vacawama can also do `for (key, value) in headers as? [String:String] ?? [:] { }` if you don’t need an `else` for the `if let`

Comment: Nice use of the *nil coalescing operator*, @Airspeed, although I'd probably put parentheses around `headers as? [String: String]` for readability.