# Cycling element in array of dictionary

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, for-in-loop

I have this code:

```
let jsonResults = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSArray

                for element in jsonResults {
                    for (chiave,valore) in element {
                        print("la chiave\(chiave) è uguale a \(valore)")
                    }
                }
```

I have an erro in this row:

```
for (chiave,valore) in element {
```

Type element Aka AnyObject does not conform to protocol 'Sequence Type'

jsonResults is an Array

and

element is an Dictionary

Can I cast element as a Dictionary?

Array is similar to this:

```
[0] : 92 elements
    ▿ [0] : 2 elements
      - .0 : NOME
      - .1 : MARIO
    ▿ [1] : 2 elements
      - .0 : CAP_DOMICILIO
      - .1 : 000000
    ▿ [2] : 2 elements
      - .0 : DATA_ULTIMO_AGG
      - .1 : 2015-09-22
```

Comment: Yes you can cast as a dictionary: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31251191/cast-while-looping-over-dictionary-in-swift/31251301#31251301

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would cast Element to [String:AnyObject]

Something like

```
            if let jsonResults = jsonResults as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                for element in jsonResults {
                    //Do stuff
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks! It's correct but swift 2 want ... as? ([[String: AnyObject]])